# Why do I get UnfinishedStubbingException here?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

The test code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class HelloWorldByHour {

    private static LocalTime REST_START_TIME = LocalTime.of(14, 0);
    private static LocalTime REST_END_TIME = LocalTime.of(16, 0);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/greeting", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    private static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
            String response;

            if (time.isAfter(REST_START_TIME) && time.isBefore(REST_END_TIME)) {
                response = "Nap time";
            } else {
                response = "Hello World";
            }

            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

When running the test I get:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:
>   -> at HelloWorldByHourTest.testMain(HelloWorldByHourTest.java:35)
>
> E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
>   Examples of correct stubbing:
>       when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
>       when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
>       doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
>   Hints:
>    1. missing thenReturn()
>    2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
>    3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

my pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>server</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>(whatever version is current)</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The test code is:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LocalTime.class)
public class HelloWorldByHourTest {

    private String sendRequest() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("localhost:8080/greeting");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String strTemp = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (null != (strTemp = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(strTemp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMain() throws Exception {

        mockStatic(LocalTime.class);
        when(LocalTime.now()).thenReturn(LocalTime.of(15, 0));
        HelloWorldByHour.main(null);
        String response = sendRequest();
        Assert.assertEquals("Nap time", response);
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have you posted the right code? Your exception is in `HelloWorldByHourTest` and it looks like what you have posted comes from `HelloWorldByHour`.

Comment: Yeah I posted the wrong code - adding the test code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call a static method on LocalDate in your `when` and `thenReturn`

Try something like that:

```
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(15,0);
    mockStatic(LocalTime.class);
    when(LocalTime.now()).thenReturn(time);
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be better, but now I'm getting `java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; @27: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'sun/net/httpserver/DefaultHttpServerProvider' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider'`

Answer (score 2):

With this call `when(LocalTime.now()).thenReturn(LocalTime.of(15, 0));` you're kind of fitting under:

> 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed.

Basically you've mocked statically the `LocalTime` class but you're also invoking the static `LocalTime.of(15, 0)` method while defining the behavior of the `LocalTime.now()`.

Depending on what you want to do, I suppose a workaround would be to create a mock of `LocalTime` before mocking the static methods, something along the lines of:

```
@Test
public void testMain() throws Exception {
    // create a mock
    LocalTime mockLocalTime = mock(LocalTime.class);
    // TODO define behaviour of mockLocalTime

    // mock the static methods
    mockStatic(LocalTime.class);
    when(LocalTime.now()).thenReturn(mockLocalTime);

    // invoke object under test
    HelloWorldByHour.main(null);
    String response = sendRequest();

    // interaction verification and/or assersions
    Assert.assertEquals("Nap time", response);
}
```